# Add External certificates to jmeter

Tags: testing, automated-tests, jmeter

How to add browser certificates to jmeter. I have an application which has an intial certificate page. When this certificate is added to browser, the user can access the other pages. Instead of login page, this procedure is followed. For different users, different certificates are generated in the browser. So, when the user enter the link and the browser has the certificate for that user, home page will be visible to that user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This blog explains the whole thing:

- https://flood.io/blog/mutual-two-way-ssl-with-jmeter/

Also check ref doc:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration

> Using KeyStore component and **Variable name holding certificate alias**
>   Variable value will be filled from CSV Data Set for example. In the screenshot of ref doc, "certificat_ssl" is a variable from a CSV Data Set.

The process is in summary the following:

1. Convert your crt files to pkcs7 and add them to keystore (see https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html) using one alias per certificate, you should have 7 aliases at end by playing:

   > keytool -import -trustcacerts -file certificate1.p7b -keystore path_to_keystore.jks -storepass  -alias "myalias1"
   >
   > keytool -import -trustcacerts -file certificate2.p7b -keystore path_to_keystore.jks -storepass  -alias "myalias2"
   >
   > ...
2. Put the aliases in a CSV file , you should have 7 rows (1 per alias)
3. Add a CSV Data Set and reference the file you created in previous step, and use as variable name certificat_ssl for example
4. Reference the keystore you created by adding to jmeter startup options:

   > -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=path_to_keystore.jks
   >   -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password_of_keystore
5. Ensure you use HTTP Client 4 as implementation for HTTP Samplers
6. Start playing

Comment: If i have more than one certificate, is it possible to execute using keystore. I have 7 thread groups each with different user rights. So, i will have 7 certificates in this case.

Comment: I did not understand the keystore configuration part. I will be having .crt file with me. How, will i get this to a variable name as mentioned. Can you help me with this.

Comment: Like i said i will have 7 certificates. Is it like, I should mention the path and password of these 7 certificates in the system.properties of the jmeter and call them by index in 7 keystores.

Comment: When i converted i got a .p7b file. How to add them to keystore - 'Convert your crt files to pkcs7 and add them to keystore (see https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html) using one alias per certificate, you should have 7 aliases at end'

Comment: I think 'keytool -import -trustcacerts -file certificate.p7b -keystore keystore -storepass -alias "myalias" ' this step i need to do with 7 certificates with different alias names. Is it like that. And should i give the 'Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=path_to_keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password_of_keystore' with all the 7 keystores created.

Comment: No create only 1 keystore, perform 7 times the import on it with 7 different aliases and then provide the keystore to commande line

Comment: Can you please update this line 'keytool -import -trustcacerts -file certificate.p7b -keystore keystore -storepass -alias "myalias"' in this way. Is it like this: keytool -import -trustcacerts -file certificate1.p7b -import -trustcacerts -file certificate2.p7b-keystore keystore -storepass -alias "myalias1" -alias "myalias2"

Comment: and where do i specify the path of the keystore in 'keytool -import -trustcacerts -file certificate.p7b -keystore keystore -storepass -alias "myalias"'

Comment: one more doubt, where should i execute this 'keytool -import -trustcacerts -file certificate1.p7b -keystore path_to_keystore.jks -storepass -alias "myalias1"' command.

Comment: From jdk bin folder, put then keystore whereever your want and reference the full path to it

Comment: is it in jrunscript.exe file.

Comment: No, you need to find your JDK home or install one, just goole download jdk

Comment: I have set the Java Home in environment variables. Where should i enter the command.

Comment: In Windows, open a CMD and run it

Comment: where do i have to place the Keystore Configuration config element. I will have 7 thread groups. should i place 7 Keystore Configuration config element within the thread groups or one within the test plan.

Comment: I have created a file certificate.jks (renamed certificate.txt to certificate.jks) in my c drive and gave a command as 'keytool -import -trustcacerts -file certificate.p7b -keystore C:\certificate.jks -storepass -alias "myalias1"'. But a message is shown as keystore file exists, but is empty.

Comment: I created a jks file with keytool -genkey -alias myKey -keystore certificate.jks command. Now the command is working. But i get another message Input not an X.509 certificate

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52370/discussion-between-gokul-and-pmd-ubik-ingenierie)